# Export Oracle Apex Calendar to PDF

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1, oracle-apex-5

I'm trying to export the Apex Calendar to PDF and I can't find any way to do it other than recreating it completely in in JS/HTML.

Previously I had a button which printed the visible month simply by printing the whole page and hiding some elements.

Now, though, I need to print multiple months, so that won't work anymore. Is there any way to do it without recreating the whole calendar in html/js and printing that?

Thanks!